# Handle any error in NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, junit, nunit

I have got a standard NUnit unit test.

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTest
    {
        [SetUp]
        public virtual void Setup()
        {   
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test01()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(10, 10);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test02()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(4, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test03()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 51);
        }

        //......a huge amount of Tests
        [Test]
        public void TestN()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
 }
```

As you see, there are a lot of tests here. What I need to do is to handle any error in each test and to get the information about the error **without** modifying the body of a test method.

So in `JUnit` there is an interface called `TestListener` which allows to handle any test error, see the error message, see the name of the test,  etc.

I didn't find something similar in `NUnit`. Does it exist? Or is there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you probably want [EventListeners](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.6.1):

> EventListeners are able to respond to events that occur in the course of a test run, usually by recording information of some kind. Note that EventListeners called asynchronously with respect to test execution and are not able to affect the actual execution of the test.

It sounds like you'll be interested in this method:

```
void TestFinished(TestResult result);
```

(As an aside, it seems odd to me that this doesn't use normal .NET events *or* provide a no-op interface implementation in an abstract class, but there we go...)

Comment: That interface didn't exist until Jon Skeet mentioned about it.

Comment: The universe created the interface out of fear because it would have collapsed if Jon Skeet had actually been mistaken.